# 画像ファイルを圧縮するツールを教えて頂きたいです。

Tags: c#, vb.net

こんにちは。

現在、ファイルサーバから社外のレンタルサーバへ、 
画像ファイルをFTP送信する機能を構築・運用しています。

**前提・実現したいこと**

運用を行う中で、日々のファイル総量が増大しており、 
FTP送信処理の通信時間を削減する事が課題となっています。

そこで、画像ファイルを圧縮・リサイズして軽量化を行う 
機能を新規に構築したいと考えているのですが、 
どのツールを使用すべきか？という点で悩んでおります。

【ツールに求める条件】

・Windows環境で動作する。 
・画像のリサイズ・圧縮ができる。 
・APIのようにプログラムに組み込み、またはコマンドラインで一括処理ができる。 
・.jpgファイルが処理できる。 
・有償/無償は問わない。

**試したこと**

まず最初に「ImageMagick(Magick.Net)」をテストしており、 
その対抗馬になるような候補を探しています。

***補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)***

OS:Windows 
開発言語:C#, VB.NET

Comment: 画像を50%に圧縮したとしてすぐに限界に辿り着くのでは。その上で「日々のファイル総量が増大」という記述が気になりました。もし同じファイルを毎日転送し直しているのだとしたら、差分管理など別のアプローチを検討した方がいいように思います。

Comment: crosspost: https://teratail.com/questions/73747

Comment: sayuri様コメントありがとうございます。そもそものファイル総量を減少させる観点でも検討をしてみたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Frameworkに含まれるWindows Imaging Componentのラッパーである`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoder`などを使用すればよいと思います。

```
// WindowsBase.dll
// PresentationCore.dll
// using System.IO;
// using System.Windows.Media;
// using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

// 元画像の読み込み
var fileName = "test.jpg";
var src = BitmapFrame.Create(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open));

// 画像の縮小
var dest = new TransformedBitmap(src, new ScaleTransform(0.5, 0.5));

// 画質を指定して保存する
var enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(dest));

// 品質: 0-100
enc.QualityLevel = 5;
using (var fs = new FileStream("out.jpg", FileMode.Create))
{
    enc.Save(fs);
}
```

Comment: pgrho様ご回答ありがとうございます。恥ずかしながらSystem.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapEncoderについては全く知りませんでした。早速実装・テストしてみたいと思います。